# treeview doesn't fit the frame

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I try to put a treeview into a subframe but it doesn't fit into the frame.

```
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        self.pipeLine =[]
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.PipeFrame = Frame(self.master,width=200,height=200).place(x=30,y=30)
        self.PipeLineFrame = Frame(self.PipeFrame,width=200,height=220,bg='white',).place(x=10,y=100)
        self.createPipeTree()
        self.createWidget()
        self.pack()
    def createPipeTree(self):
        self.PipeTree = ttk.Treeview(self.PipeLineFrame,column=("input","output"))
        self.PipeTree.column("#0",minwidth=25,width= 60)
        self.PipeTree.column("input",anchor=W,width=60)
        self.PipeTree.column("output",anchor=W,width=60)
        self.PipeTree.heading("#0",text="PipeLine")
        self.PipeTree.heading("input",text="input")
        self.PipeTree.heading("output",text="output")
        self.PipeTree.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True)
    def createWidget(self):
        self.addNode = Button(self.PipeFrame,text="click to add procedure into pipeline",command=self.addNode).place(x=10,y=20)
        self.inputBtn1 = Button(self.PipeFrame, text="F0").place(x=10,y=350)
        self.inputBtn2 = Button(self.PipeFrame, text="Mel" ).place(x=50, y=350)
        self.inputBtn3 = Button(self.PipeFrame, text="audio" ).place(x=100, y=350)
        self.inputBtn4 = Button(self.PipeFrame, text="text").place(x=150,y=350)
        self.inputBtn5 = Button(self.PipeFrame, text="f0").place(x=200, y=350)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry("800x400+200+300")
        root.title("HDI is the best")
        Application(master=root)
        root.mainloop()
```

PipeTree is supposed to fit into the PipeLineFrame (white area) but currently, it goes out of the frame like this.
[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyRdS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you layout a widget you can do it in 1 line like this:

```
Widget(root).pack()
```

or you can give it a name and use 2 lines like this:

```
name = Widget(root)
name.pack()
```

You cannot combine those 2 methods and give it name using one line. This is the error you get if you try that.

Comment: I seperate the place function. It currently looks like this :                                      
  self.PipeFrame = Frame(self.master,width=200,height=200)                           
  self.PipeFrame.place(x=30,y=30)                                                                                                   This fixes the problem but I don't know how it fixes it. Would you mind kindly explaining if you know the reason?

Comment: Because if you combine them the name becomes the output from the place() method, which is None. If you use None as a master widget tkinter defaults to the first root window.